# No visible @interface for UItableview declares the selector setSeparatorInset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6

My question is simply the title. I don't understand that if I'm using respondsToSelector why is the code checks for actual implementation ?
I'm on iOS 6, XCode 4.6

[image: warning and error]

Comment: Why are you using Xcode 4.6 and a Base SDK of iOS 6? Apple won't accept such an app. FYI - the method you are calling was added in iOS 7 which is why you get the error.

Comment: My deployment target is iOS 6, Base SDK is iOS 6.1. I know this method is in iOS 7 that's why I've checked its existence before using by respondsToSelector. I think if the object (tableView) doesn't responds to selector (setSeparatorInset) then it simply should ignore it but its giving error. Can you please help and explain why?

Comment: Your Base SDK is 6.1. You can't call methods from a newer version of iOS (such as iOS 7). And again, why is your Base SDK set to 6.1? Apple won't accept your app. They require you use Xcode 5.1 or later and fully support iOS 7.

Comment: I know I can't call method of iOS 7 from iOS 6.1 that's why I'm checking if the method exists or not. I'm not directly calling the method. I assume respondsToSelector should fail for iOS 6.x and simply ignore the method call. No?

Comment: But you are calling the method from inside the `if` statement. The compiler is complaining because for your Base SDK, the method doesn't exist. It makes no sense to ever try to call methods or use classes from a version of the SDK newer than your app's Base SDK. You must only use methods and classes valid between your selected Deployment Target and Base SDK. That's it. Anything else is wrong. The proper solution is to upgrade to Xcode 5.1, set your Base SDK to 7.1, and then the code you have will be correct.

Comment: Ok I got the solution. Thanks @rmaddy but I don't have to update the XCode version to achieve what I wanted. I've tried to answer my own question do let me know what you think. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my question:

So this has something to do with the theory than iOS or XCode version. Compiler at the time of compilation (of code) checks for the existence of method and since setSeparatorInset is not part of iOS 6.x it will not work b/c compilers don't check for 'if' clauses it simply compiles the code. 'if' clause will be evaluated at runtime. So I'm trying to call the method which isn't there simply **BUT** what I was trying to achieve is not wrong, it can be done and I can check for method of iOS 7 from code of iOS 6. What I have to do is

```
[tableView performSelector:@selector()];
```

This perform selector (is part of tableView) is executed at runtime and I'm not directly calling the method at compile time that's why this will work.

Comment: Please read my comments again. You seem to be ignoring what I am telling you. 1) What you are doing is simply wrong. With a Base SDK of 6.x it makes no sense to add code that tries to call a method from iOS 7. 2) You are wasting your time. Apple will not accept your app until your update your Xcode to 5.1 (or newer) and update your Base SDK to 7.1 (or newer).

Comment: One more thing - your use of `performSelector` won't work in this case because you won't be able to call the `setSeparatorInset:` method because you can't properly pass the argument to the method. The argument isn't a class, it's a `struct`.

Comment: You better listen to maddy, because your app will NOT be accepted on the app store.

Comment: @gnasher729 not all apps are written to be submitted to the app store.